# How can I check if I upload the picture correctly?

Tags: php, android

I'm uploading a image from Android to PHP server. But sometimes the image in the server is wrong (the image is not exactly the same, it is not complete). 
How can I check that I upload the picture correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send the picture size along with the picture in the POST request. Then on the server side, check the received size matches the size passed as POST param and send back an error in the response if that did not match.

More costly options would also be available:

- Send the hash of the file (md5 or sha1) and check on both sides if they match
- Try to read the picture in PHP and check it is a valid file
- ...

Comment: Can you get the hash or checksum (etc) of the file?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to send an image to php(if you wish send the data without loosing it), is by encoding the image by BASE64 using POST method(I would reckon a key-value pair) for this.Then at PHP you can decode back the BASE64 String to jpeg and store it.